# MVC 3 Setting uiCulture does not work

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, globalization

I'm using MVC3 in c#. I have added in Web.Config this code, with the goal to set the formatting of in UK format.

```
....
        <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
    </system.web>
```

Unfortunately the text are still displayed in US format.
Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: can you check Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture ?

Comment: And how do you output your string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the post "[Change culture based on a link MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108524/change-culture-based-on-a-link-mvc4)".  You need to inherit your Controller from a BaseController, override the BaseController's Initialize method, and use a cookie.  This is not my code, but in case that link breaks:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    HttpCookie languageCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];
    if (languageCookie != null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(languageCookie.Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(languageCookie.Value);
    }
    else
    {
    //other code here
    }

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

and

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Eng", "ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang="en-US"}, new { @class = "languageSelectorEnglish" })</li>
```

with

```
public void ChangeCulture(string lang)
{
    Response.Cookies.Remove("Language");

    HttpCookie languageCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];

    if (languageCookie == null) languageCookie = new HttpCookie("Language");

    languageCookie.Value = lang;

    languageCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

    Response.SetCookie(languageCookie);

    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```